# parsing compacted date times where no separating character between year and hour

Tags: r, regex, lubridate

I've tried a couple different methods at parsing datetime in R for this datetime, lubridate::mdy_hm seems to work but also has a strange behaviour of not handling a single element of an array?

```
datetimes <- c("10/6/20176:00 PM EDT", "10/16/20171:00 PM EDT", "10/6/201711:00 PM EDT", "10/16/201711:00 PM EDT")

substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

(time_with_bad_nas <- substrRight(datetimes, 11)) # two should be 11:00 PM ET
(date_with_bad_nas <- substr(datetimes, 0, 10)) # two are capturing the hour in the year 

lubridate::mdy_hm(datetimes[1], tz = "America/New_York")
lubridate::mdy_hm(datetimes, tz = "America/New_York")

datetimes[1] == "10/6/20176:00 PM ET"
```

Comment: `(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d{4})(\d+):(\d+)\s+([ap]m)\s+([a-z]+)` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/2WWKvv/3) gets each part. If you need to potentially get 2 year formats use this: `(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d{4}|\d{2})(\d+):(\d+)\s+([ap]m)\s+([a-z]+)`: https://regex101.com/r/2WWKvv/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could try:

```
as.POSIXct(datetimes, format = "%m/%d/%Y%I:%M %p", tz = "America/New_York")
```

output:

```
 "2017-10-06 18:00:00 EDT" "2017-10-16 13:00:00 EDT" "2017-10-06 23:00:00 EDT" "2017-10-16 23:00:00 EDT"
```